# Install Ubuntu server on RAID0

Tags: system-installation

So i have the question how do i install ubuntu server on RAID0 with 3 drives in the raid i tried googling it no results that helps me.Also tried partitioning the drive as a bot andput it in the raid no results.

Comment: Have you read through this page? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en